# How to select record where column is hashed in TypeOrm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm, argon2-ffi

My database has a table like this :

| id | rt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | value1 (hashed by argon) |
| 2 | value2 (hashed by argon) |

Which I want a record that match some value with hashed rt. somting like this :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (argon.verify(rt,"some value"))
```

How can I get something like this in TypeORM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no solution at the database level. The problem can be solved as follows :

```
  async findOneByUserAndRefreshToken(
  userId: number,
  refreshToken: string,
  ): Promise<Device | undefined> {
  const devices = await this.repo.find({
  where: {
    rtExpiresIn: MoreThan(new Date()),
    user: { id: userId },
  },
  });
  const device = devices.find((device) =>
  argon.verify(device.refreshToken, refreshToken),
  );
  return device;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the query function to execute raw SQL query like this:

if you are using Typeorm > 0.3.0

```
constructor(
    @InjectDataSource()
    private dataSource: DataSource,
  ) {}
```

```
this.dataSource.query(`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (argon.verify(rt,"some value"))`)
```

if you are using Entity extend BaseEntity, you can use it like this:

```
YourEntity.query(`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (argon.verify(rt,"some value"))`)
```

Comment: argon is a js library, Its not possible to call it within raw query